# Enabling SNMP traps for Switch Crashes - 3750 stack

Tags: cisco, snmp, stacking

We recently had an issue where one 3750 switch of a stack crashed due to a slow memory leak. The slow memory leak has been resolved but we'd like to be notified of it by SNMP if it happens in the future.

What is the command to enable system crashes to be reported to SNMP?

Comment: In my experience, depending on the crash maybe the stack can't send traps because forwarding plane is down. In most crashes, you only get the traps when system gets recovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/40360-SNMPcoldStartTraps.html

It looks like you'd need to use

**snmp-server enable traps snmp cluster**

According to http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3750scg/swsnmp.html that should give you notifications for cold start, warm start and cluster change - possible changes in the cluster commander or member availability would let you know that you'd lost a switch prior to the warm-start alert.  Don't know if the *whyReboot* object is included in the trap or if you'd need to poll that in response to the trap being sent.